# Project structure when using VueJS, VuelidateJS with NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, es6-modules

My web development is principally intranet sites and web front-ends for embedded devices using NodeJS.

My current structure is to have everything in one NPM package.  I run NodeJS behind Nginx, and let Nginx serve css/image/client-side-javascript files directly from `public`.

I'm starting to use VueJS and Vuelidate, both of which use the now ES6 modules system - e.g. `import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'`.

While I've (rather hackily) made these work with my current structure, I think the time has come to get into the world of Javascript build-systems/bundlers.

If I use VueJS's preferred option of WebPack, how should I change the structure of my code?

- Should I have one NPM package for the frontend (generated by `vue-cli init`) and another for the Express backend app?
- Should I put my Express App into the generated Vue frontend package?
- Should I use `browserify` to do the job of WebPack and stay with my existing structure?
- Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why you’re intent on putting your JavaScript code in other packages. If you have an application then you can keep your raw JavaScript files in there, along with the build script(s). Someone should be able to check your application out and be able to build it.

If you’re looking to get started with a build system, then a nice “bridge” might be to use Mix, a project created by Laravel for building front-end assets such as Sass and JavaScript. It uses Webpack under the hood, but in turn exposes a more user-friendly, fluid API.

If you go down this route, then you could put your raw JavaScript files in a **lib/** or **src/** directory. You could then use Mix to compile these components like this:

```js
mix.js('lib/your-entry-point-script.js', 'public/js/app.js');
```

Your entry point script would just be the script that `require`s all your other scripts and components and the script that you want “built”. Mix would then compile that and place the resultant script at **public/js/app.js**.

Mix itself is just a npm package, so all you need to do is `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev`.

You can read more about Mix at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix

Comment: This article makes two NPM packages, "client" and "server".  https://medium.com/@anaida07/mevn-stack-application-part-1-3a27b61dcae0

Comment: @fadedbee So…? I’d only create distinct client and server packages if you were actually going to consume them in multiple, separate applications. If it’s just the same application but a front-end and a back-end, just keep the code in the same repository.